# Using Socket.io, AngularJS and Express, client listening on different port than which the server is running at

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io, passport.js

I was trying to implement a chat application with authentication. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.htmlxprs.com/post/6/creating-a-realtime-image-sharing-app-with-ionic-and-socketio-tutorial) to make the chat application which uses Socket.io.

When I used this tutorial the server is listening at port 8000 whereas the client is running at port 8100. The Socket URL is at 8000 and the chat application is working perfectly. However when I try to use methods of Express such as `app.get()`, I cant seem to make it work. I think the cause is that the port of the local host is 8100 and I am listening on 8000. I am using `app.get()` and AngualrJS to authenticate using PassportJS. Please can someone help me out as I have been stuck on this for a while. Thanks and I would really appreciate any help. Maybe I am thinking about this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

If your client side app is making calls to 8100 then a server running on 8000 is not going to respond. If an error message is printed to the console on the client or the server, please add that to your question along with any and all relevant code so that we can help properly

Answer (score 0):

It's kind hard to tell without seeing the code, but it could be that your client is not making a GET request to 127.0.0.1:8000 or you didn't setup ExpressJS correctly. Post some code so people can get a better idea of what's causing the issue. You can also test that your server is listening to port 8000 with `curl 127.0.0.1:8000`. If you get a response, then your server is fine and ExpressJS is listening to the correct port and, therefore, it must be the client.